# Titanium - Listener callback is of a non-supported type: __NSDictionary

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I've a problem with Titanium SDK >= 6.1.0 GA and Ti.App.fireEvent under iOS. Until SDK 6.0.4 GA using Ti.App.fireEvent with a JSON dictionary as parameter was working fine, but since 6.1.0 to last GA (6.3.0) I'm receiving the following message:

```
Listener callback is of a non-supported type: __NSDictionaryM
```

I've seen this line inside KrollBridge.m that could cause this log message:

```
- (void)fireEvent:(id)listener withObject:(id)obj remove:(BOOL)yn thisObject:(TiProxy*)thisObject_
{
    if (![listener isKindOfClass:[KrollCallback class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"[ERROR] listener callback is of a non-supported type: %@",[listener class]);
        return;
    }

    KrollEvent *event = [[KrollEvent alloc] initWithCallback:listener eventObject:obj thisObject:thisObject_];
    [context enqueue:event];
    [event release];
}
```

**ONLY** fails when I try the app on device, on simulator works fine!.

Adding some NSLogs and running the app:

Console:

```
Simulator:
[DEBUG] :  Firing app event: event_test
[DEBUG] :  Listener type: KrollCallback
[DEBUG] :  OK

Device:
[DEBUG] :  Firing app event: event_test
[DEBUG] :  Listener type: __NSDictionaryM
[ERROR] :  Listener callback is of a non-supported type: __NSDictionaryM
```

Code:

```
Ti.App.addEventListener('event_test', fun);
Ti.App.fireEvent('event_test', data: {"ID": 0, "Value": "Test"});
```

I have no idea why. I've the feeling that is a bug introduced in 6.1.0 GA and it reproduces until the last GA available.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is the same issue reported here **[Ti.App.fireEvent JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-25346)** which is marked as **Resolved in SDK 6.3.0.GA**

Do update your Ti SDK to latest 6.3.0.GA as it's quite stable than other 6.x versions.

---

#### Recommended Solution :

Read here why to avoid using [Ti.App.addEventListener](http://www.tidev.io/2014/09/10/the-case-against-ti-app-fireevent-2/) & follow below steps to set global event listeners to pass around anything you want.

1. Create a js file with any name, let's say, **events_dispatcher.js** in your project's **app -> lib** folder.
2. Add this code line in this file : **`module.exports = _.clone(Backbone.Events);`**
3. Now replace this code of yours **`Ti.App.addEventListener('event_test', fun);`** with this one :

   ```
   var eventHandler = require('events_dispatcher');

   eventHandler.on('event_test', fun);


   // to avoid duplication of adding the same event
   // make sure to remove this event when you close the controller
   // or you are planning to re-create the controller 

   eventHandler.off('event_test', fun);
   ```
4. Finally replace this code **`Ti.App.fireEvent('event_test', data: {"ID": 0, "Value": "Test"});`** with this one - **`require('events_dispatcher').trigger('event_test', data: {"ID": 0, "Value": "Test"});`**

This code method might seem little more, but it's the most recommended way & optimal solution for all your needs to replace Ti.App.fireEvent. Stick to it & you will have a safe way to call around any method with any kind of data.

Comment: I'm trying with 6.3.0 GA but same results. It seems a fireEvent bug not resolved yet :(

Comment: Do not worry. I have added a new way to deal with global or app-wide event handling. I strongly advise you to stick to the new solution I have added in my answer. It's always safer to use it.